How to implement a generic publish–subscribe pattern where methods of subscribers that receive calls can be registered at the publisher?
More generic publish–subscribe pattern
I was looking for a publish–subscribe pattern that is advance in terms of more generic.
The usual publish–subscribe pattern that I know of has virtual functions as call back functions in the subscriber interface/base class and an overridden version in the derived class as well. This way it is easy for a publisher to call the subscriber via the interface.
Example:
class IIssue {
...
};

class ISubscriber {
public:
    virtual void receive( const IIssue* pIssue ) = 0;
};

class Subscriber : public ISubscriber {
public:
    virtual void receive( const IIssue* pIssue ) {
        ...
    };
};

However, I was looking for a more generic version with the following properties:

the methods of subscribers that receive calls can be registered at the publisher, ad-hoc, using member pointers and smart pointers
a subscriber method that can receive calls is flexible in amount and types of parameters, without using tuple's or an interface class
to be able to extend the pattern for asynchronous forwarding of parameters to multiple subscriber
to be able to extend the pattern being able to inquire a return code of a single provider instead of forwarding parameters to multiple subscriber

Nice to have:

subscriber does not need to derive from a base class, necessarily

I already found a solution that works with C++20 only, which I will publish soon. May be you are faster and better.
I tried the following:

implementing a class to encapsulate a 'shared_ptr' and a member pointer a calling object

trying this I had a lot of problems casting member pointers
especially when implementing inquiry of return codes I had to use reinterpret_cast and eventually encountering segmentation faults


implementing a class to use 'function' and 'bind' to encapsulate a calling object

it has taken quite a time to find a solution to bind the parameters to 'function' objects



Given code of application
Publisher
The publisher is a template class that "carries" the types of the publishing function. This way specific publisher can be created easily by driving from that template class. The publisher also provides the function to register the subscribing object and the method to be called back.
class MessagePublisher : public Publisher< Time, PtrMessage > {
};

Subscriber
class MessageSubscriber {
public:
    string     msCollectedInChannel1;
    string     msCollectedInChannel2;
public:
    virtual void receiveInChannel1( Time time, PtrMessage ptrMessage ) {
        msCollectedInChannel1 += format( time, ptrMessage);
    }
    virtual void receiveInChannel2( Time time, PtrMessage ptrMessage ) {
        msCollectedInChannel2 += format( time, ptrMessage);
    }
    virtual string format( Time time, PtrMessage ptrMessage ) {
        string  sFormatted;
        sFormatted += "@";
        sFormatted += to_string( time );
        sFormatted += ": ";
        sFormatted += ptrMessage->getMessage();
        sFormatted += "\n";
        return sFormatted;
    }
};

Example parameters
The following declarations are just examples of types that can be published and fit to the rest of the code.
typedef
    double  Time;

class Message {
public:
    virtual string getMessage() const = 0;
};

typedef
    shared_ptr< Message >   PtrMessage;

class IntMessage : public Message {
public:
    int     mnMessage;
public:
    IntMessage( int nMessage ) : mnMessage{ nMessage } {
    }
    virtual ~IntMessage() {
    }
public:
    virtual string getMessage() const {
        return std::to_string( mnMessage );
    };
};

class StringMessage : public Message {
public:
    string  msMessage;
public:
    StringMessage( string sMessage ) : msMessage{ sMessage } {
    }
    virtual ~StringMessage() {
    }
public:
    virtual string getMessage() const {
        return msMessage;
    };
};

Includes and its declarations
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::to_string;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;

Main
auto ptrPublisher1 = std::make_shared< MessagePublisher >();
auto ptrSubscriber1 = std::make_shared< MessageSubscriber >();
auto ptrSubscriber2 = std::make_shared< MessageSubscriber >();

ptrPublisher1->registerCallback( ptrSubscriber1, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel1 );
ptrPublisher1->registerCallback( ptrSubscriber2, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel1 );

ptrPublisher1->publish( 123, make_shared< IntMessage >( 1001 ) );
ptrPublisher1->publish( 124, make_shared< StringMessage >( "S1002" ) );

cout << "ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel1 = \n" << ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel1 << '\n';
cout << "ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel1 = \n" << ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel1 << '\n';

ptrPublisher1->registerCallback( ptrSubscriber1, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel2 );
ptrPublisher1->registerCallback( ptrSubscriber2, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel2 );

ptrPublisher1->publish( 125, make_shared< IntMessage >( 1003 ) );
ptrPublisher1->publish( 126, make_shared< StringMessage >( "S1004" ) );

cout << "ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel1 = \n" << ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel1 << '\n';
cout << "ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel1 = \n" << ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel1 << '\n';
cout << "ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel2 = \n" << ptrSubscriber1->msCollectedInChannel2 << '\n';
cout << "ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel2 = \n" << ptrSubscriber2->msCollectedInChannel2 << '\n';

Question
How does the code look like (ideally the complete program), using the STL? ...and in particular:

How to register and hence how to store combinations like
ptrSubscriber1, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel1 into the
publisher?
How to bind final parameters when publishing with particular parameters?
How can this be applied to create an asynchronous version?
How can this be applied to create an inquiring version?


you can look at how Entt Library does signals and views, though beware of library boundaries, as entt type system doesn't work across library boundaries, and neither does a lot of things like rtti type id and std::any, you will have to create a library for storing those types and doing string comparisons on the first lookup to allow it to work across library boundaries, like what Qt does for its type system

In modern C++ it is no longer required to make "Messages" to be able to write obeservers, that's a very object oriented way of thinking. More generic is to register callback functions (and the arguments will contain the data you want to send). Like this:
#include <format>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace details
{
    struct callback_unsubscribe_itf
    {
        virtual ~callback_unsubscribe_itf() = default;
        virtual void unsubscribe(std::size_t) noexcept = 0;
    };

    template<typename... args_t>
    struct callback_registration_t
    {
        callback_registration_t() = default;
        callback_registration_t(const callback_registration_t&) = delete;
        callback_registration_t& operator=(const callback_registration_t&) = delete;

        callback_registration_t(std::size_t i, details::callback_unsubscribe_itf* itf) :
            id{i},
            unsubscribe_itf{itf}
        {
        }

        callback_registration_t(callback_registration_t&& other)
        {
            id = other.id;
            other.id = 0ul;
        }

        callback_registration_t& operator=(callback_registration_t&& other)
        {
            id = other.id;
            unsubscribe_itf = other.unsubscribe_itf;

            other.id = 0ul;
            other.unsubscribe_itf = nullptr;

            return *this;
        }

        ~callback_registration_t()
        {
            if (unsubscribe_itf != nullptr)
            {
                unsubscribe_itf->unsubscribe(id);
            }
        }

        std::size_t id{ 0ul };
        details::callback_unsubscribe_itf* unsubscribe_itf{ nullptr };
    };
}


template<typename... args_t>
class callbacks_t : public details::callback_unsubscribe_itf
{
public:
    auto subscribe(std::function<void(args_t...)> callback)
    {
        std::size_t id{ 0ul };
        details::callback_registration_t<args_t...> registration{ ++id,this };
        m_callbacks.insert({ id,callback });
        return registration;
    };


    void operator()(args_t... args)
    {
        for(auto& [id,callback] : m_callbacks)
        {
            callback(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        }
    }

private:
    void unsubscribe(std::size_t id) noexcept override
    {
        m_callbacks.erase(id);
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::function<void(args_t... args)>> m_callbacks;
};


class ObservableClass
{
public:
    auto register_observer(std::function<void (int,std::string)> observer)
    {
        return m_call_observers.subscribe(observer);
    }

    void do_something()
    {
        m_call_observers(42,"Hello");
    }

private:
    callbacks_t<int,const std::string&> m_call_observers;
};


int main()
{
    ObservableClass o;

    auto registration = o.register_observer([](int value, const std::string& str)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("value = {}, str = {}\n", value, str);
    });

    o.do_something();
}


Thank you. That was fast, I didn't expect this. Your solution provides hints in the right direction. This will take some time to analyse this since the given code is ignored. I use object orientation intentionally as you do to store observers (subscribers). I have doubts that this fits the intended question. In my example the subscribers are objects, intentionally. The subscribers are objects and such objects shall be registered together with the member function. A lambda function is not a subscriber object. If that hasn't been described in the question well enough I am going to clarify this.

Please, have look on the first bullet in section "Question" and the call ptrPublisher1->registerCallback( ptrSubscriber1, &MessageSubscriber::receiveInChannel1 );in the example.

In the end what you want to achieve is that "a function" with "arguments" is called (through inheritance or not). std::function + lambda expressions provide an excellent way of decoupling observers/subscribers from publishers. The nice thing is you don't have to write any infrastructure (abstract baseclasses with callbacks or any message data structures to derive from).  Also I was fast because I had this lying around

What I want to achieve is written in the question. There is a given code: MessageSubscriber and a function like receiveInChannel1 to be registered. This is the given context of the question. Please, consider the context, respect the question and may adapt your answer. Especially your intro shows that you have something different in mind. Ask what you don't understand before providing answers to alternative question that have not been asked.
Thank you.

Your answer has some advantages in another context, in another architecture and/or programming paradigm. Each paradigm has its advantages and disadvantages. I am programming in C++ and Haskell. In Haskell you even don't need a callback_unsubscribe_itf or callback_registration_t or callbacks_t  as an infrastructure. A callback wouldn't even make sense. The pure functional lazy evaluation paradigm of Haskell could also be applied in C++. The least thing one wants to to hear is an advice like: "You don't need a callback.", implying that the question is wrong. Compare this with your intro.

P.S.: However, I admit that your answer provides some interesting pattern where I can learn from. Take my upvote, even tough your answer is incomplete. The best and complete answer will receive an accept.

The callbacks_registration is not a necessity, it allows for RAII unsubscribe if you no longer want the subscription to be active.  Calling a receive function on a ISubscriber is as much a callback as anything else :)

Who doesn't know callbacks_registration is not a necessity? You could even directly call 'std::cout << std::format("value = {}, str = {}\n", 42, "Hello");'. In the context of the question for me this is like: "A banana is yellow." I have one that is even green. So, context please. Fast is good, accurateness has value.
